# How to use generic `Number` for `Comparator.comparing`

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I have a list of class that I want to sort:

```
class Student {
    private Integer studentId;
    private Double scoreA;
    private Integer scoreB;
    private Long scoreC;

    // ... getter/setter...
}
```

And I want to make a helper class (with static methods) that can be used to sort the `Student` list:

```
public class SortHelper {
    public static <T> void Sort(List<T> list, Function<T, Double> fn) { // Double
        Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(fn));
    }
}
```

However, the above method only takes `Double` - but I'd like to pass all `Number` object to the method:

```
public static <T> void Sort(List<T> list, Function<T, Number> fn) { // `Number`
    Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(fn)); // Error!
}

// so that I can do:
List<Student> students = loadStudents();

SortHelper.Sort(students, Student::getScoreA); // Double
SortHelper.Sort(students, Student::getScoreB); // Integer
SortHelper.Sort(students, Student::getScoreC); // Long
```

When I use `Number` instead of `Double`, it gives an error `The method comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U>) in the type Comparator is not applicable for the arguments (Function<T,Number>)`

My questions are:

1. Why is using `Number` instead of `Double` not possible?
2. How to improve `SortHelper` to use `Number` instead of `Double`?

Please help me out..!

Comment: `SortHelper.Sort(students, Student::getScoreA)` is not a big improvement over `students.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getScoreA))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're facing this issue because [`Comparator#comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) expects a [`Function<T, U>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) whose output `U` extends [`Comparable<? super U>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html).

[`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html) does not implement `Comparable<? super Number>`.

One solution is to specify a new generic type that extends `Number` **and** also extends `Comparable`:

```
public static <T, U extends Number & Comparable<? super U>> void Sort(List<T> list, Function<T, U> fn) {
    Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(fn));
}
```

Or equivalently, you can use [`List#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)):

```
public static <T, U extends Number & Comparable<? super U>> void Sort(List<T> list, Function<T, U> fn) {
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(fn));
}
```

This is what's known as an [*intersection type*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/IntersectionType.html).